# Good 'Bug' with Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I was pasting my CV from Word into Stack Overflow Careers, and I noticed that if you paste bullet points, they translate over.

```
• My Accomplishment here
```

Bug? Or Feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call it:
• Expected behaviour for cut/paste
• Not worth fixing if it isn't
• A shortcut to typing Alt+0149 like I just did entering this answer

Comment: Why type Alt+0149 when you can let SO's Markup do the work for you?

Comment: @Chris: I never said there wasn't a better alternative, I just answered the question of whether this was a bug or not.